# PHP OOP, jQuery and MVC

Tags: php, jquery, php-include

I'm relatively new to PHP OOP and cant seem to be able to call functions in a PHP Class via a controller. My current setup is:

- index.php
- class.Class1.php
- functions.controller.php
- script.js

Within **index.php** i include **class.Class1.php**, make a new Class object and use a couple of it's methods to output some HTML. I want to use js functions in **script.js** (called by using the onclick attribute of a link) to communicate with **functions.controller.php**, which in turn will call methods in **class.Class1.php** and return the data to **script.js** who will in turn output HTML on **index.php**.

The problem is that i dont know how to use the methods to get the data of that particular object. When i call the controller:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'functions/functions.controller.php',
    data: 'r=' + 'h',
    success: function(data){
        $('.showing').html(data);
    }
});
```

I get a 500 Internal server error:

> [25-Oct-2011 01:24:06] PHP Warning:  include(classes/class.Class1.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/Joey/Desktop/root/Test/functions/functions.controller.php on
>   line 7
>
> [25-Oct-2011 01:24:06] PHP Warning:  include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'classes/class.Class1.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php') in
>   /Users/Joey/Desktop/root/Test/functions/functions.controller.php on
>   line 7
>
> [25-Oct-2011 01:24:06] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Class1' not
>   found in
>   /Users/Joey/Desktop/root/Test/functions/functions.controller.php on
>   line 9

This is controller.php:

```
include('classes/class.Class1.php');

$in = new Class1;

echo $in->getData();
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this? Also any other PHP OOP MVC with AJAX tips are welcome. If more of my current code is needed, i'll be happy to post.

Comment: Do you really need to make a request to the controller directly??? It looks like some form of MVC what you are trying to achieve. Don't you have a URL something like: `/my/url` which is handled by the controller?

Comment: What is the error message in your web server log for the 500 response? Also, there seems to be some inconsistency between the filenames listed at the top of your question and the references in code. Could you clean that up?

Comment: @PeeHaa MVC does not automatically imply URL rewriting so I wouldn't jump to that assumption

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know if i need to make a request directly. Like i mentioned earlier, i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Phil I'm running this locally using MAMP and am using the Chrome Developer Tools Console, which only said: error 500 Internal Server Error. Where would i be able to view more?

Comment: @JoeyvanOmmen Try `/Applications/MAMP/logs` or `/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs`

Comment: @Phil Put the error messages in the description above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're getting your include paths mixed up.

I'm assuming your file structure is actually

```
index.php
classes/class.Class1.php
functions/functions.controller.php
script.js
```

To include `class.Class1.php` from `functions.controller.php`, you need to traverse up a directory first to get out of the `functions` directory, eg

```
// PHP >= 5.3
require_once __DIR__ . '/../classes/class.Class1.php';

// PHP < 5.3
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../classes/class.Class1.php`;
```

Comment: Ah, how embarrassing :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: However this did solve my problem and i am able to call upon the methods of the class now, I'm still forced to make a new object of that class every time, while i want to retrieve the data of an existing object. Any idea how i could solve this?

Comment: @Joey: there isn't an existing object. The entirety of each script is run with each request. Data stored in PHP variables doesn't persist beyond the request being handled. Extensions have the possibility of storing data associated with resources they create. Data can be serialized in `$_SESSION` automatically, but is generally only accessible within the same session (multiple users don't share sesions). Databases are the primary mechanism to persist data.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't find "classes/class.Class1.php" because its parent ("/Users/Joey/Desktop/root/Test/") isn't among the paths that PHP searches when including files. Add "/Users/Joey/Desktop/root/Test/" to the include path, either in [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), in [.htaccess](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) (if running PHP as an Apache module) or [programmatically](http://php.net/set_include_path). You can use the document root in the last case. For example, if the is the document root is "/Users/Joey/Desktop/root/" (the parent of the folder to be added to the search path):

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR 
                 . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Test');
```

If you place the code that updates the include path in an initialization file that lives in the folder to be added, you can use:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__);
```